# Finding NaN Values in Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the difference between two Pandas `MultiIndex` objects of different shapes. I've used:

```
df1.index.difference(df2)
```

and receive

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

My indices are str and datetime, but I suspect there are `NaNs` hidden there (the floats). Hence my question:

What's the best way to find the NaNs somewhere in the MultiIndex? How does one iterate through the levels and names? Can I use something like `isna()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `MultiIndex` are not implemented many functions, you can check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#multiindex).

You need convert `MultiIndex` to `DataFrame` by [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) first:

```
#W-B sample
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(np.nan,1),(1,1),(1,2)])

print (idx.to_frame())
         0  1
NaN 1  NaN  1
1   1  1.0  1
    2  1.0  2

print (idx.to_frame().isnull())
           0      1
NaN 1   True  False
1   1  False  False
    2  False  False
```

Or use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(list(idx.tolist())))
     0  1
0  NaN  1
1  1.0  1
2  1.0  2
```

Because:

```
print (pd.isnull(idx))
```

> NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex

EDIT:

For check at least one `True` per rows use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = idx.to_frame()
print (df[df.isna().any(axis=1)])
        0  1
NaN 1 NaN  1
```

Also is possible filter `MultiIndex`, but is necessary add [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

```
print (idx[idx.to_frame().isna().any(axis=1)].remove_unused_levels())
MultiIndex(levels=[[], [1]],
           labels=[[-1], [0]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good. Very simple follow-up: how could I filter it for rows which are `True`? (My multi-index is very large)

Answer (score 2):

We can using `reset_index` , then with `isna`

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(np.nan,1),(1,1),(1,2)])
df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],index=idx)
df.reset_index().filter(like='level_').isna()
Out[304]: 
   level_0  level_1
0     True    False
1    False    False
2    False    False
```

Comment: this is nice - but when I do `reset_index` it doesn't prepend `level_` (is this default behaviour?) so filter doesn't find anything

Comment: @JoshFriedlander since my index dose not have name , if you index have name , just using your index name